# d3 - Axis Label Transition

Tags: d3.js, transition, axis-labels, cubism.js

In Mike Bostock's cubism demo (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/demo-stocks.html), there is a cursor which displays the values of all horizon charts on display. Furthermore, the cursor text shows the time axis point in time. As the cursor text obscures an axis label, the label fades.

I am working on a similar display with d3.js (but not cubism). I have all working except that fade portion. I have searched through the CSS in the developer's window, searched the source code (as best I could), but I don't understand what manner of magic is being used to accomplish this feat. I've even looked through SO "axis label transition" questions, but I have failed to connect the dots on xaxis label transitions.

How does that fade in/out when obscured by text happen?

UPDATE:
I think I located the event script area where this happens - its just a little over my head at the moment - can anyone help me decipher what this event listener is doing? Specifically, in the second g.selectAll in the else clause below - what data (d) is being used here? What is causing this event to fire?

This is the coolest part of the display (outside of the horizon charts), I would love to figure this out ...

```
context.on("focus.axis-" + id, function(i) {
      if (tick) {
        if (i == null) {
          tick.style("display", "none");
          g.selectAll("text").style("fill-opacity", null);
        } else {
          tick.style("display", null).attr("x", i).text(format(scale.invert(i)));
          var dx = tick.node().getComputedTextLength() + 6;
          g.selectAll("text").style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return Math.abs(scale(d) - i) < dx ? 0 : 1; });
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I just checked what you're saying and I don't know how I didn't pay attention to it before.

Comment: Makes me feel a little better anyway  ... thanks.

Comment: OK found a clue ... with the edited update above.

Answer (score 0):

I used this as reference to accomplish the same effect.

I'm not sure what the context variable is or how the id's are set or what the tick flag references but what I did was simply update the opacity of the ticks according to their proximity to the mouse.  With this, the vertical tick fades as well as the label text.

```
  svg.selectAll('.x.axis .tick').style('opacity', function (d) {
    return Math.min(1, (Math.round(Math.abs(d3.mouse(svg.node())[0] - x(d))) - 10) / 15.0);
  });
```

This way, the opacity is set to 0 if it's within 10 pixels, and fades from 1-0 between 10 and 25.  Above 25, the opacity would be set to an increasingly large number, so I clamp it to 1.0 using the Math.min function.

My labels are slightly rotated, so I also added an offset not shown inside the formula above (a +3 after [0]) just to make it look a bit nicer.  A year late to answer your only question, but hey it's a nice effect.

Answer (score 0):

same answer as Kevin Branigan's post, but using the d3 scale to calculate the opacity value.

```
var tickFadeScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([10,15]).range([0,1]).clamp(true);
svg.selectAll('.x.axis .tick').style('opacity', function (d) {
 return tickFadeScale(Math.abs(d3.mouse(svg.node())[0] - x(d)));
}
```